# Getting value from datepicker and assign to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form for booking an appointment with 1 inputs and 2 selects:
**First**: input with jQuery that can select a date.
**Second**: select with a list of hairdressing (not relevant).
**Third**: select with a list of available times based on date.

I got in the database all the time availables based on the date, so my goal is :

When the user selects a date , my query populates the third select with the list of available times so my query requires the date that he picked.
How can I get the value of the date picked and use it in php for my query?

---

HTML/View:

```
<h1>Book Reservation</h1>
                <b><p>Select Date:</p></b>
                <input id="datepicker" name="date" width="270" style = "display: block; float: center;" disabled required>

    <script>
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
        });
    </script>

    <?php include "../../Models/appointment/hdquery.php"?>
    <b><p style = "margin-top: 10px; ">Select Hair Dressing :</p></b>
    <select  class="select-css" name = "hairdressing">
     <?php include "../../Models/appointment/populatelisthd.php"?>
     </select>
     <b><p style = "margin-top: 10px;">Select Time:</p></b>
     <?php include "../../Models/appointment/timesquery.php"?>
     <select  class="select-css" name = "times"><
     <?php include "../../Models/appointment/populatelisttimes.php"?>
     </select><p style="margin-top: 10px;">

     <input type="submit" value = "Confirm">
```

---

hdquery and populatelisthd in the includes are irrelevant to my question, so i won't show them.

---

timesquery:

```
<?php
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','cappeli');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT t.`hour` FROM `times` t LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `time` FROM `reservations` WHERE `date` = '$date' GROUP BY `time` HAVING COUNT(*) > 2) r on r.time = t.`hour` WHERE r.time IS NULL ");
?>
```

If you notice in the query there is a `WHERE date=$date`
I want to get this date from the input field of datepicker and on every change i need the query to update the time. How do I do that? (PS: I got another php file to populate it but I need the result from `timesquery` to populate the select )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an [AJAX request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) each time the user selects a date. For this to work you can use the datepicker library's [onSelect` event](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect).

1. First let's get rid of the `timesquery.php` and `populatelisttimes.php` files:

```html
    <?php include "../../Models/appointment/hdquery.php"?>
    <b><p style = "margin-top: 10px; ">Select Hair Dressing :</p></b>
    <select  class="select-css" name = "hairdressing">
     <?php include "../../Models/appointment/populatelisthd.php"?>
     </select>
     <b><p style = "margin-top: 10px;">Select Time:</p></b>
      <!-- -->
     <select  class="select-css" name = "times">
     <!-- Options will be added here dynamically using jQuery -->
     </select><p style="margin-top: 10px;">

     <input type="submit" value = "Confirm">
```

2. Now let's listen to the date "selection" in your *jQuery*:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'timesquery.php',
            data: {
                'date': date,
            },
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('select[name=times]').html(data);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('An error has occured.')
        });
    }
});
```

3. Lately, let's print out the options HTML in the `timesquery.php` file, i believe your `populatelisttimes.php` file takes care of printing the option so i will just include it:

```php
$date = $_POST['date']; // <====== Here is our date variable, you need to escape this!!!
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','cappeli');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT t.`hour` FROM `times` t LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `time` FROM `reservations` WHERE `date` = '$date' GROUP BY `time` HAVING COUNT(*) > 2) r on r.time = t.`hour` WHERE r.time IS NULL ");

include __DIR__ . '/populatelisttimes.php';
```